# How to History of commands with dates in linux?

Tags: linux, unix

How to get history of commands with dates...like  i need complete log of my system what ever commands executed in machine, from which Ip they logged in at that time and and What is command executed?
Is it Possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not easily.

You can see who logged in from where with `who` or `last`.

You can see the history of the commands of the last shell which exited in their home folder in the file `$HOME/.bash_history`. BASH doesn't log the timestamp in this file, though, so there is no way to tell when the commands were executed. You can see this when you execute

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T " history
```

A lot of the commands in the history will have the same date/time and if you look more closely, you'll see that this is in fact the date/time of the file `.bash_history`.

It should be possible to download the sources for BASH and compile your own version which does more extensive logging. Just be careful that you don't log commands read from script files (or your computer probably won't even boot anymore).

Also note that you need to do the same for all the shells which your users are using. And you need to make sure that they don't have their own copy of the shell.

Related:

- [How to log all Bash commands by all users on a server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93566/how-to-log-all-bash-commands-by-all-users-on-a-server)
- [HOWTO BASH Audit / Command Logger](http://www.pointsoftware.ch/howto-bash-audit-command-logger/)